# OOP: Pros / Cons of Events Orientation VS Direct Access

Tags: android, oop, apache-flex

I am working with Flex SDK for mobile, how ever this question is about Object Oriented Programming.

I have a view stack mechanism that is responsible for managing the views, I can access it from any view class and I can request it to navigate to another view **B** or to close the current view **A**.

My question starts from its method to navigate to another view:

```
addView(Class);
```

I need to pass it the requested view class name, than it creates that view, open it, and add it to the view stack. Lets call this method **direct access**.

I thought about alternative method where **A** will rise an event, some thing like: GameRequest when the user clicks on the "Play Now" button. I will have some controller, that will listen to GameRequest event, and call the addView() method with **B** class. Lets call this method **events orientation**.

So here is my pros and cons, tell me what do you think, am I missing anything?

---

**Direct access**

- + Easy to code
- + Most of the frameworks has it as default: Flex mobile SDK, Android SDK, and more...
- - Creates dependency between views

**Events orientation**

- + No dependency between views
- + Easy to maintenance
- + Easy to see all the places who start start/open the view (I did it with the same controller that listen for 4 kinds of events to show the game screen, his execute is the same)
- - More complicate to code first time, need to add extra event and controller classes.

Comment: I'd think there's a slight performance cost for the event handling and additional classes, which _might_ perhaps be noticeable on mobile. Flex isn't the best solution for performance anyway. Combine that with the fact that mobile apps usually have a fairly simple structure, which means the maintenance cost of the 'direct access' method isn't very high, and I think you know why these mobile SDK's chose to take the first route by default.

Comment: @RIAstar "fairly simple structure" I can argue with that. "there's a slight performance cost for the event handling", while it's true for flash native events mechanism, I am working with signals, its based on C# events implementation and it does not have a performance problems. So event performance are very depends on your implementation.